# Without login credentials how to store unique phone credentials in Android Development?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Some applications don't need to get your email, username, password credentials to know who you are. For example you download a mobile application. After that you made some choose like you are man, you are 25 years old etc. And the application remembers that until you remove application. Is there a unique ID for Android devices to get? I have made a snake game recently. I get email and password information to know which user is while I was changing score. But for this usage I don't know how to proceed.  By the way I am developing my application using Jetpack Compose on Android Studio.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate your question with what use case you want to achieve? Why do you  want to differentiate unique device? If you are not using an remote database you don't need to uniquely identify each device. Moreover, you can store user specific details(such as name, age) in local database or shared preferences.

Comment: Store these values in the datastore or shared preference if you want to access it later. Your question is not precise, consider rephrasing it.

Comment: Yes using SharedPreferences could solve my problem thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make an in-app database using Sqlite or room database. Save all data into it when user input it for the first time.

Than when user want auto login system just use that previous data. That's it simple thing. Let me know If I can help you